# How to redirect a page and disguise its url?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, webserver

I need to do the following on my apache webserver :

Redirect any URL starting with :

```
 http://mydomain1.com/archive 
 to 
 http://mydomain2.com/archive
```

Is there a way using mod-rewrite or RewriteEngine to disguise that URL, so that the URL that appears in the browser is mydomain1.com ?   I don't want to give away the fact that we are switching servers.

Comment: It is possible, we have done it but it took time  to figure it out. If I find the relevant code I will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in the .htaccess from domain1.com/archive

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain2.com/archive [P]
</IfModule>
```

Edit: Tell me if you've tried this and if it worked or not.

Answer (score 2):

you could try a reverse proxy.  This will allow you to take one url and forward  the request to another server without the end user knowing.

Comment: Using a proxy with mod_rewrite requires mod_proxy, and a configuration example can be found here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible using mod_rewrite. If host changes then it has to be an **external redirect** using `R` flag.

A possible workaround is to make server to server call from inside your code on mydomain1 to mydomain2. If using php you can use [file_get_contents function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to make this happen.